# UIToolbar with UILabels Flexible space not working

Tags: iphone, xcode, uilabel, uitoolbar

I am creating a toolbar that will have 2 labels on it.

On the left I want my tax label.
On the right I want my total label.

This is my code for setup in the viewDidLoad method.

```
self.taxLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0 , 11.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, 21.0f)];
self.taxLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.taxLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.taxLabel.text = @"$$$$.$$ TAX"; 


self.totalLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0 , 11.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, 21.0f)];
self.totalLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.totalLabel.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[self.totalLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentRight];
self.totalLabel.text = @"$$$$.$$"; 

// create the bar button item where we specify the label as a view to use to init with
UIBarButtonItem *taxButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.taxLabel];

UIBarButtonItem *flex = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

UIBarButtonItem *totalButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.totalLabel];

NSArray *toolbarItemArr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:taxButton, flex, totalButton, nil];

[infoBar setItems:toolbarItemArr animated:YES];
```

The problem I'm having is that the flexible space doesn't seem to be doing anything.
If I set the total label text to align left it overlaps the tax label. It's almost as if they're being added to the toolbar on top of each other.

Also the labels can overlap each other. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. But I think it's got to do with how I init the frame.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I suspect your labels are too wide. Make them less wide and see if things work better. For a quick test, set each to 100.0 wide and see if the flexible space is working then. (Or send the taxLabel and totalLabel sizeToFit messages...)

Comment: That's it I think. However it creates a new problem for me. I have the wordwrap mode on and two lines. I setup the tax labels string like this @"$123,456.78\n$123,456,789.00" If the first line doesn't fit it will wrap it around. I don't think I can fix this unless I have two labels. Can I put one uibarbutton above another one?